# Fetch data based on user id from MYSQL and display in recyclerview in android studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

So I have a database that contains 2 tables, one for user activities named `tblactivity` and the other named `tblusers`:

`tblactivity` contains multiple data for a user and I want to display entries in `tblactivity` in a recyclerview based on the logged-in user whose data I fetched from `tblusers`. `tblactivity` has `userid` column and I would like to know how to go about this.

**EDIT**: More Details:

So am using slim framework: DbConnect.php

```
//Method to get emails of a particular user

    public function getActivity(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, userid, subject, message FROM tblactivity");
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $userid, $subject, $message);
        $users = array(); 
        while($stmt->fetch()){ 
            $user = array(); 
            $user['id'] = $id; 
            $user['userid'] = $userid; 
            $user['subject'] = $subject; 
            $user['message'] = $message; 


            array_push($users, $user);
        }             
        return $users; 

    }
```

My index.php code

```
$app->get('/allactivity', function(Request $request, Response $response){
$db = new DbOperations; 
$users = $db->getActivity();
$response_data = array();
$response_data['error'] = false; 
$response_data['users'] = $users; 
$response->write(json_encode($response_data));
return $response
->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
->withStatus(200);  
});
```

Now in android studio:

My Activity.java model:

```
public class Activity {

private int id;
private int userid;
private String subject;
private String message;
private String to;


public Activity(String subject, String message) {

    this.id = id;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
    this.to = to;

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public int getUserid() { return userid; }
public String getSubject() { return subject; }
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public String getTo() { return to; }

}
```

User.java Model

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String email;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String companyname;
private String postcode;
private String city;
private String state;
private String phonenumber;
private String address1;
private String country;
private String status;
private int currency;
private String credit;
private String language;
private int email_verified;


public User(int id, String email, String firstname, String lastname, String companyname, String address1, String city,
            String state, String postcode, String country, String phonenumber, String status, int currency, String credit,
            String language, int email_verified) {

    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.companyname = companyname;
    this.address1 = address1;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.country = country;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    this.status = status;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.credit = credit;
    this.language = language;
    this.email_verified = email_verified;


}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastname;
}
public String getCompanyName() { return companyname; }
public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public String getState() { return state; }
public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public String getPhonenumber() {
    return phonenumber;
}
public String getStatus() { return status; }
public int getCurrency() { return currency; }
public String getCredit() {
    return credit;
}
public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}
public int getEmail_verified() { return email_verified; }


}
```

I am using Retrofit client to get the json output from php.

```
    @GET("allactivity")
Call<List<Activity>> getActivityData();

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please i have provided my details and my code in a answer reply to this thread. Please take a look and let me know if you can help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly your question goes about data handling. Now there are two possibilities, if you have a local database on the device, then you will have to create a SQLLiteOpenHelper and pass in a SQL Query, in which you clarify what data you need an example could be:

```
SELECT * FROM tblactivity WHERE userid = 30;
```

In this case you would get all the info about the user with the id 30. Now if you have an online database, you have to write a php file, which allows you the communication with the sql database, if I add this here as well, it would go too far. Here is tutorial you could check out about that: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

As soon as you have uploaded the php file via an ftp handler, you need to open an internet connection with a link like this: www.mydomain.com/database.php?userid=30 .

You pass in a restriction of which users you are in interested in. In your php file you can then get the data with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblactivity WHERE userid = ".$_GET["userid"];
```

Then you need to read the incoming data and parse it. My choice is to use json_encode in your php file and to store the incoming data in the app as JSON. You will need to inform yourself about that as well, but it's not all too difficult.

If you have received the data, you need to create a custom object, where you store all the necessary information:

```
public class User {
    public User(String name, int _id, String email){
        //save the information in local variables
    }
    public String getName(){
         return mName;
    }
    //Add more methods to get and set the different variables.
}
```

Then the next thing you have to do is create a custom Adapter to populate the items of the RecyclerView. But again, this would be too much to explain here. Here would be the link to another tutorial: https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd

It may seem like a lot now, but I have also just started with this, and you'll get the hang of it fast.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using slim framework to code in php and generate the json. See my details in my answer response to this post .

Comment: Also i would like to display the fetched data in recyclerView using loggedin user id from sharedpref. Can you help?

Comment: What exactly do you need there? Do need to make a query based on the saved user Id?